# What kind of script can batch resize images?

Tags: mysql, linux, image, image-processing, batch-processing

I have a MySql database on Apache that contains various items (`iphone`,`ipad`).

Each item in the DB contains a URL which is a link to its full-sized picture, located on an external server.

What kind of script, can take each product image, resize it proportionally (for example, to 100px width, and height according to proportion), and save it on my own server as `/images/iphone_100.jpg` for example? The image also needs to be web-optimized.

Answer (score 1):

For the image resizing part, you could use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

If the files are already in the images folder and you have direct access to it
Simply do 
`convert -resize "100x>" *.jpg -strip -quality 80 -set filename:f "%t_100" '%[filename:f].jpg'`

This will create a copy of each picture, resize the width to 100px if it's greater than that and output it with originalfilename_100.jpg. -strip removes EXIF data and the -quality flage set the jpg quality for web optimization. You can probably go lower than 80 for small images like that.

If you don't have direct access, export a list of the files 
`SELECT image_url FROM your_table INTO OUTFILE '/list/of/urls.txt` 
then wget the files from the list with the -i flag, run imagemagick with mogrify instead of convert and upload them via FTP or whatever method you usually use.